# how to convert list of strings into list of lists using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of strings as shown below:

```
value=['[a,b,c]', '[d,e,f]']
```

I want to convert it into list of lists and assign it to a variable

```
**needed output**
value=[['a','b','c'], ['d','e','f']]

g,h=value
print(g)
**output**:['a','b','c']
print(type(g))
**output:**list
```

how to achieve this using python?

Comment: `[s[1:-1].split(",") for s in value]`

Comment: Is all the data in strings formatted exactly as in your example, or are there also cases where the data is nested (`'[[1, 2], 3]'`)? Are there empty lists (`'[]'`) or empty strings (`''`)? Did you look at `.split()`?

Answer (score -1):

**Hi Swati,**

1. First what you have to do is, you need to go through all the elements of the list "value" (which are strings) and remove the first and last indexes which are square brackets (you can do it using the list slicing in python),
2. Second you need to remove the commas from the string and you can do it using python's module *"re"*
3. Third you need to move through all the elements of the strings and store the elements in the new list
4. Fourth append the list of elements to the *output* list

**Here's the complete code**

```
import re
value=['[a,b,c]', '[d,e,f]']
output = []
for i in value:
    charactersList = []
    val = re.sub(",","",i[1:-1])
    for j in val:
        charactersList.append(j)
    output.append(charactersList)
print(output)
```

**Happy Coding!!!**

Comment: While the example in the question is single characters, the title and text says "list of strings". Your code would split apart every character irrespective of where the commas are, and may not be the expected behavior.

Comment: look at the needed output mentioned by the person who asked the question before marking the answer as not useful, Look at the Input value and then the output value, my code does the same thing and outputs the correct list ... Hope you are getting my point